# How could I edit a users from this API in local state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to have an edit button to edit the users first name, last name from the api but only update the input in local state. I've done a lot of research but can't find exactly what I'm looking for. I'm trying not to bring in other libraries (other than lodash possibly?). I've found a lot of other examples but its bringing in other libraries. Any suggestions would help (even on the code I have currently to help clean it up a bit.)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import User from './User'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      searchTerm: '',
      alphabetical: 'az'
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20")
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.results);
        this.setState({ users: response.data.results });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    let sortedUsers;
    if (this.state.alphabetical === "az") {
      console.log("sorted");
      sortedUsers = this.state.users.sort((a, b) =>
        a.name.first > b.name.first ? 1 : -1
      );
    }

    let filteredUsers = sortedUsers;

    if (this.state.searchTerm)
      filteredUsers = this.state.users.filter(u =>
        u.name.first.startsWith(this.state.searchTerm) || u.name.last.startsWith(this.state.searchTerm)
      );

    const userNames = filteredUsers.map(u => {
      return <User
        key={u.email}
        name={u.name.first}
        last={u.name.last}
        image={u.picture.medium}
        email={u.email}
        city={u.location.city}
        state={u.location.state}
        cell={u.cell}
      />;
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Search for user:
              <input
              type="text"
              name="searchTerm"
              value={this.state.searchTerm}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <select
          name="alphabetical"
          value={this.state.alphabetical}
          onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option selected value="az">
            A to Z
          </option>
          <option value="za">Z to A</option>
        </select>
        {userNames}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App
```